# BundleReference and caching

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm confused about BundleReference and caching. For a new web app VS2013 includes the following in Site.Master:

```
   <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
```

and this winds up rendering as:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Now, when I make changes to Site.css, the browser typically doesn't see the changes because Site.css has been cached. I've seen countless approaches to handling this issue that typically all boil down to doing something like this:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css?v=SomeVersionNumber" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

But BundleReference is rendering the link tag and it doesn't seem to have any support for adding a version. What is the *right* way to deal with this so that changes to Site.css are guaranteed to be delivered to the client along with the dependent html?

Answer (score -1):

You can add the revision querystring in your BundleReference tag, like this

```
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css?rev=1" />
```

This will be rendered as:

```
<link href="/Content/css?rev=1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: but the bundle is not updated as it cached, so the parameter is useless